# Confusion about Casting among Signed and Unsigned

Tags: c++, type-conversion, unsigned, short

Recently I am learning about casting among data type. So I  try this:

```
    unsigned int a = 4294967295;
    int b = -1;
    if (a == b) {
        cout << "a == b" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "a != b" << endl;
    }

    unsigned short c = 65535;
    short d = -1;
    if (c == d) {
        cout << "c == d" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "c != d" << endl;
    }
```

The output is:

```
a == b
```

```
c != d
```

I have learned that -1 and 65535U are equal when encoded using 16bits. So why variable c and d are not equal when compared?

I try to use explicit conversion:

```
    unsigned short e = static_cast<unsigned short>(d);
    if (c == e) {
        cout << "c == e" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "c != e" << endl;
    }
```

The output is

```
c == e
```

so what is the differnece?

My system is win11 x64.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you confuse the terms. A cast is what you write in your code to explicitly trigger a conversion. There are no casts in your first snippet

Comment: If the types are smaller than `int`, they are both first promoted to `int`.

Comment: During promotion of integer values, the compiler will do *sign extension*, so a negative value keeps its value. Both `c` and `d` are stored as `0xffff` in memory, but when promoted `c` will become `0x0000ffff` while `d` becomes `0xffffffff`.

Comment: try `unsigned short d = -1;` to see the difference

Comment: The first is equivalent to `a == static_cast<unsigned int>(b)`, the second to `static_cast<unsigned int>(c) == static_cast<unsigned int>(d)`. Print all four converted values and look.

Comment: *I have learned that -1 and 65535U are equal when encoded using 16bits.*  Try `std::memcmp(&c, &d, sizeof c) == 0` if you want to compare memory bytes rather than value interpretation.